# How can I download ICS file for an event?

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is there any option where the .ics files gets downloaded on a click at the front-end for the selected event?

Answer (score 1):

You can download an .ics file using the `{exp:calendar:icalendar}` tag: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/icalendar/

From the documentation:

> The Calendar:iCalendar tag is available for event exporting purposes. It outputs an ICS (RFC-2445) compatible file, which can then be imported into other programs such as Google Calendar, Apple Calendar, Microsoft Outlook, Lightning, etc.

Putting this tag on a template will trigger a file download of an .ics file with your calendar data.